# Como puedo comparar 2 listas (multidimensional) por su Key?

Tags: python

como podria comparar 2 listas dependiendo de un key de la misma?  en python, actualmente puedo comparar 2 listas transformando esas listas a sets y luego con (set1 ^ set2) tengo la comparacion pero esto me compara los 2 sets completos con todas las keys yo quisiera comparar solo una key ejemplo comparar esas 2 listas pero solo tomando en cuenta el indice 1 donde se encuentra "victor", "fecp" etc..

Ejemplo

```
lista1 = [
[1, "victor"],
[2, "FECP"]
]

lista2 = [
[1, "victor"],
[2, "ASD"]
]
first_set = set(map(tuple, lista1))
secnd_set = set(map(tuple, lista2))

diferencia = (first_set ^ secnd_set)
```

Puedo compararlas completas pasandolas a sets y luego comparandolas completamente pero quiero comparar por ejemplo su name como podria hacer?

que comparando por su name el resultado me de:

```
[[2, "ASD"]]
```

Que no compare toda la lista sino que compare los elementos por su Indice

Answer (score 1):

Como quieres comparar elementos por su índice, una opción fácil es utilizar diccionarios:

```
lista1_indexada = dict(lista1)
lista2_indexada = dict(lista2)
diferencia = [[clave, valor] for clave, valor in lista2_indexada.items() if lista1_indexada[clave] != lista2_indexada[clave]]
diferencia   # [[2, 'ASD']]
```

La última expresión se denomina list comprehension y está capturando sólamente los elementos para los cuales los valores son diferentes.

Answer (score 0):

Si he entendido bien tu problema, y quieres comparar dos listas por su indice, realmente dos listas comparadas por sus indices, es ver si en cada indice de la lista hay lo mismo, que es lo mismo que decir si las **dos listas son iguales**:

```
lista1 = [
[1, "victor"],
[2, "FECP"]
]

lista2 = [
[1, "victor"],
[2, "ASD"]
]

lista2 == lista2
```

**Salida**: `False`